# Youtube dynamic playlist add to chromecast queue

Tags: video, youtube, chromecast

I have embedded youtube player in my website and it works fine with chromecast when a single video is supplied to the iFrame. However, when I add multiple videos, on browser, it plays the videos one after another. When I cast the entire tab, the videos play one after another. However, when I cast from youtube player, it stops after playing the first video. Is there something that I am missing? The embedded player code is as below.

```
<iframe width="1000px" height="600px" src="//www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&playlist=<videoId_1>,<video_id_2>,<video_id_3>&autoplay=1&iv_load_policy=3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```